# Гарантированный доступ к данным в интернете

Tags: веб-программирование, c++

Есть задача, сделать так, чтобы неким данным в интернете всегда был доступ. Например они находятся на site.ru/data.data, а данные типа md5(time()+rand()). Кешировать нельзя, надолго терять связь с ними тоже не стоит.

Что можно сделать:

- site2.ru/dataserver.txt -  сделать список зеркал. Нужен второй сайт и другие сложности.
- DNS. a.site.ru, b.site.ru - ссылающиеся на резервные адреса. DNS медленно обновляется и не дает возможность указывать порт.
- TXT DNS. Было бы неплохо указать всю информацию в записи типа TXT, но чем ее можно считать из C++ под линуксом и виндой?
- Возможно вы сможете подсказать оптимальный вариант?

Это используется в программе, которая раздается пользователям и что-то менять потом проблематично.

Comment: можно воспользоваться любым cdn (к примеру Akamai или от Amazon). Но если нужна надежность - тогда по любому нужно два и более сервера, желательно в разных датацентрах.

Comment: @KoVadim, это слишком круто для моей задачи.